# Snapping a vertex group to another

Tags: modeling, snapping

Is it possible that the selected vertices of a mesh move at the position of the vertices of another like the image below? (the number of vertices is same.)

Thanks in advance

[image: Snap the vertices at once]

Comment: Is this question about Blender or Houdini? in Blender you can try [_Bridge Edge Loops_](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html?#bridge-edge-loops)

Answer (score 1):

## Destructive Method: Bridge

1. Duplicate the vertices of the left mesh <kbd>X</kbd>. Go to the target mesh, duplicate the target vertices (box select <kbd>B</kbd> and duplicate <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) and separate them <kbd>P</kbd> by selection. Join the target vertices with the original mesh.
   [image]
2. Select the outer edges of the remaining target mesh, which are now unconnected (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> for edge loop selection). <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select the outer target vertices. Then bridge them with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > **Bridge Edge Loops**. Recalculate the normals of the target vertices. <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>
   [image]

## Non-Destructive Method: Shapekeys

1. Select the vertices in question of the left original mesh. Assign them to a group ('Group'). Create the *Basis* shapekey and a new shapekey. In the new shapekey, move the original vertices close to the target mesh vertices. (As close as possible.)
   [image]
2. Set the Shapekey influence value to `1.0`. Add a Shrinkwrap modifier to the original object. Set the target object as **Target** and the Group as **Vertex Group**. Set the method to **Nearest Vertex**. The vertices now snap to the nearest vertex of the target mesh.
   [image]
3. Apply the modifier as shapekey. You can delete the temporary shapekey.
   [image]